# How do you track the participants of a multisignature transaction?

Tags: wallet, privacy, multi-signature

How to glean which wallets were involved in a multisignature transaction?

Comment: What do you mean by 'which wallets'? Do you mean who owns the keys involved, or just which keys were used to sign, or what?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6032/516 in a general sense, when it comes to tracking transactions?

Answer (score 1):

a multisig tx (e.g. 2of3) has a redeem script, which is basically the hash of three bitcoin addresses. This hash is included in the bitcoin transaction. As per today's knowledge, this hash can only be reproduced, if you have the three initial adresses. If you don't have them, then you can't know, which adresses were initially involved. A hash is a one way. Easy to generate a hash, but extremly difficult (or even impossible) for today's computers, to revert back.

Comment: The redeemscript is revealed after the output is spent though; maybe that is what OP is asking about.